# Hide the "Show more fonts" button in wxFontDialog, wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

How do we remove the  "Show more fonts" button when we use wx.FontDialog?

```
dlg = wx.FontDialog(self, data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialogs in `wxPython` are created using internal OS calls, so they look differently on different operating systems and `wxPython` only provides interfaces to them. The dialog you see is just the typical Windows 7 `Font` dialog box.

So the question is whether we can change system dialog boxes, and the easy answer to this question is: No, that's impossible. See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsribbondevelopment/thread/a2e51d56-ccba-4be7-b4b4-7db96bb5d149) thread for details.

However, Windows 7 has several Font dialog templates and you can choose what template to use, but that is the hard way (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Customizing_the_Font_Dialog_Box_for_Win7) MSDN article for details).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrey said, you can't do it since wxPython is wrapping the native dialog. The only way around this limitation besides what he mentioned is to roll your own font dialog with wx.Dialog.